# AngularJS not working with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I'm trying to get angular working with ruby on rails however when I put an angular scope in the html it works if I do for example 1+1, but if I bind a number or string to a scope, it doesn't work.

How would I go about solving this

app.js

```
var MotorgearDen = angular.module("MGD", []);
MotorgearDen.controller('motorHome', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.data.greeting = 'Hello'


}]);
```

homepage.html.erb:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>1 + 1 = {{1+1}}</p>

{{ data.greeting }}
<%= "You are logged in" if user_signed_in? %><br />
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete if user_signed_in?%>

<%= current_user.login if user_signed_in? %>
```

Comment: Show, please, how do you initiate your `MotorgearDen` controller?

Comment: I think, you get error in console `data is not defined`. Create object `data` in your controller. Like this `$scope.data={};`.

Comment: you need to initialize the `data` object in the controller. also, you might want to change the string content of the `greeting` :)

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you have included ng-controller in html.
I don't see any data property assigned to $scope. So u can't assign any property further to it.

Try this.

```
$scope.data = {
 greeting: 'something'
}
```

Or store directly on scope like

```
$scope.text = 'domething'
```